# Obtener los datos de un usuario

Tags: php, poo

Estoy a prendiendo oop con php y quiero tomar los datos de un usuario.

Este es mi codigo.

dbh.class.php

```
class Dbh {
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $user = 'root';
    private $pass = '';
    private $dbName = 'prueba2';

    public function connect() {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->$host . ';dbname=' . $this->$dbName;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->$user, $this->$pass);
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $pdo;
    }
}
```

usuario.class.php

```
class Usuario extends Dbh {
    public function getPost(){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($id);

        $resultado = $stmt->fetch();
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

y asi intento obtener sus datos

```
$id = 1;

$user = new Usuario();
$user->getPost($id);

echo 'Hola '.$user['nombre'];
```

El resultado deberia ser `Hola Antonia` pero tengo este error `Notice: Undefined property: Usuario::$ in` y estoy confundida.

Espero me ayuden, gracias.

Comment: La funcion `getPost` hace un return de `$resultado`. Por lo que nunca se asigna nada al objeto `Usuario`.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar mejor tu comentario @granch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código, tanto en la praxis como en la lógica.

### En la praxis

- Debes indicar el parámetro para `$id` en `getPost()`
- No estás ejecutando bien la consulta preparada. Los valores deben ser pasados como array en el `execute()`.

Corregimos esos dos puntos:

```
class Usuario extends Dbh {
    public function getPost($id){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE id = ?";
        $stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array($id));

        $resultado = $stmt->fetch();
        return $resultado;
    }
}
```

En el contexto, tampoco es correcto el código. Debes hacer una asignación a la llamada a `getPost()` para tener una referencia de lo que este método retorna, por ejemplo:

```
$id = 1;

$user = new Usuario();
$mUser=$user->getPost($id);

echo 'Hola '.$mUser['nombre'];
```

Con ambas cosas se resuelven los errores en la praxis.

Los errores lógicos son más delicados, pero me permito señalar algunos.

### En la lógica

Lo primero que llama la atención es que tu clase `Usuario` extienda de `Dbh`, que supongo que es la clase de conexión. Esto es un grave error lógico. Una clase `Usuario` podría extender de una clase `Persona` por ejemplo, porque compartiría propiedades comunes como podría ser el nombre, apellido, etc. Hacer extender una clase de otra cosa utilitaria como es la conexión es un error de diseño.

Las clases que son de entidades (como `Usuario`)  deberías pensarlas como un molde para construir objetos de ese tipo, sin importar de dónde vengan los datos. Si mañana quieres usar esa clase para informarla con datos que vengan de un archivo de texto, un XML, un JSON, de Firebase, etc ... vas a estar arrastrando con la conexión en la clase sin necesidad de usarla.

Es un tema muy amplio que daría para mucho, sólo quiero llamar la atención sobre el error de lógica de querer hacer extender una clase entidad de una conexión a la base de datos que es más parte del contexto que de otra cosa.

Dicho eso, en `getPost()` faltan controles. ¿Qué pasa si no hay conexión?  ¿qué pasa si no hay filas? ¿qué pasa si hay error en la consulta?, etc. Nada de eso es controlado. Debes concebir tu programa como algo robusto, que prevea todos los posibles problemas, los controle y de una respuesta adecuada. Si no haces eso, tu código podría romperse en un determinado escenario, dejando al usuario con un crash o en el limbo.

Y, si vamos más lejos, habría que preguntarse, ¿qué hace un método llamado `getPost()` en una clase llamada `Usuario`? ¿No debería ese método ser parte de una clase `Post`? Una de las grandes ventajas de la POO es que nos permite programar pensando las cosas como son en realidad. Un poco de metafísica no viene mal cuando se diseñan las clases y las relaciones entre ellas mediante la herencia.

Comment: Cedano, la verdad me dejaste anonadada y trato de entenderte pero bueno, soy un mujer, jajaja. Pero teniendo en cuenta lo que me dices, ahora tengo otro error y es que no esta definada las variables de coneccion: `Notice: Undefined variable: host in` y voy a tener que cambiar todo entonce? o empezar de cero?

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera La intuición femenina es mucho más fina, así que el problema no es ese :) Son quizá conceptos nuevos y por eso no entiendes algunos, pero poco a poco los irás entendiendo. El error que tienes ahora puede deberse a lo que te mencionaba en la 2ª parte de la respuesta: no hay control sobre si la conexión es válida o no, parece que le estás pasando como `host` el nombre de una variable que no existe. Puede que ese error se encuentre en tu clase `Dbh`. Es importante que entiendas bien la cuestión de la herencia para diseñar tus clases, sino tendrás un spaghetti en el código.

Comment: Eres muy amable, esto es muy nuevo y voy a tener que ver mas videos. Ahi actuelice mi pregunta e inserte el codigo de conexion y si esta definida las variables `host`, esta como privada o deberia ser publica?

Comment: No @AntoniaHerrera si estás usando a las propiedades dentro del contexto de la clase nadamás [aunque sean privadas si las puedes acceder](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.visibility.php)

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera el problema en `Dbh` es que estás usando `$` después de `$this->`, lo cual no es correcto. Cuando usas `$this` no debes poner la `$` de los nombres de variable. Debes corregir esa parte de este modo: `$dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName;
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass);` No sé de qué fuente estarás aprendiendo, pero en tu forma de crear la conexión PDO también hay malas prácticas. Se recomienda crear la conexión dentro de u bloque `try ... catch` para controlar posibles errores de conexión, pero ese es otro tema.

Comment: Creo que a veces una ve sin ver y al estar tanto tiempo intentando resolver algo, deja de mirar lo que esta a simple vista. Estaba siguiendo un tutorial y el persona que lo hace escribe esto `mysql:host=`, pero yo como una tonta lo escribi mal. Pido disculpas por eso y gracias por sus palabras. Me han hecho de mucha ayuda. Este es mi facebook por si me quieren seguir. [Anto Herrera](https://www.facebook.com/anto.herrera.33483) Besitos!

Comment: @AntoniaHerrera me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Si tienes cualquier problema con el código puedes preguntar en Stackoverflow. Hay muchos programadores que participan de este sitio y sin duda te echarán una mano con cualquier error o problema de código que surja. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, eres muy gentil y admiro tu paciencia, yo me volveria loca. Si queres, seguime en facebook. Deje el link arriba.